# Provide monitoring Information from running jobs in Quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I use Quartz 2.2.1 in a cluster with a JDBC JobStore. I store informations from the jobs in their JobDataMaps for monitoring reasons - for example if an error occurs while job execution. Now I am trying to provide additional monitoring informations while the jobs are running. But the JobDataMap is stored after the execution only. Does anybody have an idea to provide such monitoring informations with Quartz?

Comment: have you looked at what quartz exposes over JMX?